# Are Google's mlengine environments available as images to download?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I would like to be able to test/debug code in an exact replica of the mlengine environment, is this environment available to download anywhere as (say) a docker image?

I am aware of `gcloud ml-engine local train`, however I have a bug that appears to only manifest when using `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training`. I have done my best to replicate their environment using virtualenv and matching tensorflow versions, but the problem persists.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/86700090

Comment: What is the value of HYPER_PARAMS.job_dir in your logs (you print this out at the top of main()).

Comment: Can you contact us via cloudml-feedback@google.com please? We will help you to have a repro env.

Comment: @GuoqingXu thanks, I'll do that